# OpenZeppelin default FixedSupply contract not sending balance to sender

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm deploying a very standard openzeppelin ERC20 contract with the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract ERC20FixedSupply is ERC20 {
    constructor() public ERC20("Fixed", "FIX") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }
}
```

This code is present at openzeppelin's own documentation here: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc20-supply

My steps: installed truffle, installed openzeppelin, created the file with the above code, flattened with truffle flattener and deployed using remix with metamask (Kovan network). Deployment successful and I get the contract address fine, but when I try to check the sender address wallet for the token, it's empty.

Here's what I see on metamask after adding the token:

[image]

Token page shows this: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tokens?q=0x87B62aAcEc6d304c26d4514ccD9Cb4F6Bc3bc114

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code is correct. You may share a link to your Etherscan transaction for people to look into it. Ideally you verify the contract as well: https://etherscan.io/verifyContract

Comment: here's my contract 0x87B62aAcEc6d304c26d4514ccD9Cb4F6Bc3bc114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment seems to be incorrect. The contract you deployed has only an empty fallback function that reverts: https://kovan.etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x87B62aAcEc6d304c26d4514ccD9Cb4F6Bc3bc114.

My guess is that in Remix you clicked on `ERC20` (or some other incorrect contract) instead of `ERC20FixedSupply`.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.9;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract ERC20FixedSupply is ERC20 {
    constructor() public ERC20("Fixed", "FIX") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }
}
```

This code works for me in Remix deployments: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xd7a047e2921dc43d486a97a9b1dedb7fe0f2c705c347f7b807d80c1ef8e2754e.

Make sure you select the correct contract inside Remix:

[image]

Comment: I moved the whole flattened contract to remix.It's a single file

Comment: You're right. The new solidity visuals got me confused.

Comment: @raphadko Great. I also just added an updated answer with importing directly from Github. That makes it easy to test stuff in Remix.